# Xpath looping issue to parse a simple HTML table to a php array

Tags: php, html, xpath

So my previous question:
[PHP Convert html table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888578/php-convert-html-table-to-json)
was quickly dismissed as a duplicate and I'm still struggling to get to what I need. I think it's mostly a logic problem in the loops and I need someone else to take a look at it.

Given this table as an example:

```html
<table id="Details" class="DATA_TABLE DATA_TABLE_WO_TOTAL">
  <tr>
    <th>Application</th>
    <th>Version number</th>
    <th>Virtual Administration Server</th>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>Device</th>
    <th>Installed</th>
    <th>Last visible time</th>
    <th>Last connection to Administration Server</th>
    <th>IP address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sD">some text</td>
    <td class="sD">10.2.5.3201</td>
    <td class="sD"></td>
    <td class="sD">Thin PC</td>
    <td class="sD">PC#</td>
    <td class="sD">date</td>
    <td class="sD">date</td>
    <td class="sD">date</td>
    <td class="sD">ip address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <tr>
    <td class="sD">some more text</td>
    <td class="sD">10.2.5.3201</td>
    <td class="sD"></td>
    <td class="sD">Thin PC</td>
    <td class="sD">PC#</td>
    <td class="sD">date</td>
    <td class="sD">date</td>
    <td class="sD">date</td>
    <td class="sD">ip address</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to create an array (that I can later convert to a json) where the th tags are the keys and then all the td tags inside each other tr is the data corresponding to these keys. I have the following php code:

```html
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($cleantable2); //this is the table above
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//table/tr') as $tr){
        $tmp = [];
                foreach($xpath->query('//table/tr/th', $tr) as $th){
                        $key = $th->textContent;
                        foreach($xpath->query('td', $tr) as $td){
                                $tmp[$key] = trim($td->textContent);
                        }
                }
                $result[]=$tmp;
        }
var_dump($result);

?>
```

It does get the keys right, but not the data, sample output:

```html
  [89]=>
  array(9) {
    ["Application"]=>
    string(13) "192.168.6.104"
    ["Version number"]=>
    string(13) "192.168.6.104"
    ["Virtual Administration Server"]=>
    string(13) "192.168.6.104"
    ["Group"]=>
    string(13) "192.168.6.104"
    ["Device"]=>
    string(13) "192.168.6.104"
    ["Installed"]=>
    string(13) "192.168.6.104"
    ["Last visible time"]=>
    string(13) "192.168.6.104"
    ["Last connection to Administration Server"]=>
    string(13) "192.168.6.104"
    ["IP address"]=>
    string(13) "192.168.6.104"
  }
```

As you can see, it only picks up the IP address for each key and not the rest of the data. What am I doing wrong? Can someone help out and not just dismiss this as a duplicate? Been trying to figure this out for over a day, I'm pretty sure my issue is just not looping correctly but I'm not seeing it...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$strhtml='
<table id="Details" class="DATA_TABLE DATA_TABLE_WO_TOTAL">
  <tr>
    <th>Application</th>
    <th>Version number</th>
    <th>Virtual Administration Server</th>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>Device</th>
    <th>Installed</th>
    <th>Last visible time</th>
    <th>Last connection to Administration Server</th>
    <th>IP address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sD">some text</td>
    <td class="sD">10.2.5.202</td>
    <td class="sD">Plato</td>
    <td class="sD">Thin PC</td>
    <td class="sD">PC#</td>
    <td class="sD">date a</td>
    <td class="sD">date b</td>
    <td class="sD">date c</td>
    <td class="sD">10.25.100.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <tr>
    <td class="sD">some more text</td>
    <td class="sD">10.2.5.321</td>
    <td class="sD">Socrates</td>
    <td class="sD">Thick PC</td>
    <td class="sD">PC#</td>
    <td class="sD">date x</td>
    <td class="sD">date y</td>
    <td class="sD">date z</td>
    <td class="sD">10.25.100.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>';
```

Given the above html snippet perhaps the following does what you need? The comments should help see what I have done

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $strhtml );
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
/* find the `th` elements */
$col = $xp->query( '//tr/th' );

/* temp arrays */
$tmp=$out=$keys=array();


if( $col->length > 0 ){
    /* get all headers as keys */
    foreach( $col as $node )$keys[]=$node->nodeValue;

    /* get all table cell data - store in single array */
    $col=$xp->query( '//tr/td[ @class="sD" ]' );
    foreach( $col as $node )$tmp[]=$node->nodeValue;

    /* split data into chunks according to number of columns */
    $rows=array_chunk( $tmp, count( $keys ) );

    /* combine keys and chunks */
    foreach( $rows as $row ){
        $tmp=array();
        foreach( $row as $i => $value ) $tmp[ $keys[ $i ] ]=$value;
        $out[]=$tmp;
    }

    echo json_encode( $out );
}
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "Application":"some text",
        "Version number":"10.2.5.202",
        "Virtual Administration Server":"Plato",
        "Group":"Thin PC",
        "Device":"PC#",
        "Installed":"date a",
        "Last visible time":"date b",
        "Last connection to Administration Server":"date c",
        "IP address":"10.25.100.1"
    },
    {
        "Application":"some more text",
        "Version number":"10.2.5.321",
        "Virtual Administration Server":"Socrates",
        "Group":"Thick PC","Device":"PC#",
        "Installed":"date x",
        "Last visible time":"date y",
        "Last connection to Administration Server":"date z",
        "IP address":"10.25.100.2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I needed it to do!!